Get the first element of a column using pandas
I have a csv file, which has couple of columns. The one I'm interested is 'Date' column and more specifically I'm interested by the first row of that column, the first date that appears.
So i have a file that i read as a csv using pandas:
FILE = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)

# doesnt work
last_scraped_date = FILE['Date'][0]

test_last_date = FILE.iloc[1]['Date']

the code above just prints nan. However if i directly print FILE['Date'] it starts printing me the whole column.
All i want is to print the first row of that 'Date' column.

FILE.iloc[1]['Date'] seems to imply that the element located in the first cell of that column is nan. If you want to get the first non-null, just run .dropna() first

Note that iloc is zero based so first row would be FILE.iloc[0]["Date"]

@ifly6 using .dropna() achieved, what I was looking for. The first element is actually a null, even tho when I open it using excel doesnt show so. Anyways you helped me

You had the right idea to use iloc function. You can do it like this instead:
FILE['Date'].iloc[0]


gave me the same result, using .dropna() as @ifly6

if you print FILE.head() what do you get?

lol okay, when printed the head, i saw that i was using 'Date' - which is null, but I needed to use 'date'... the lowered date wasn't visible when I opened the csv using excel. But yeah using iloc works as expected now. IDK if the problem was of excel displaying the csv content, or how the file was created.
